# How to use do_action_ref_array?

Tags: hooks, actions

I have a plugin which has this method in it that is supposed to have a hook for custom validation. I have two issues:

1. I'm not sure how to call it (have posted my attempt below)
2. It looks like the plugin has a bug in it because I can't get at $cart_key?

Plugin code with the hook:

```
public function validateCustomFields( $value, $form_id, $cart_key )
{
    $decoded_value = json_decode( $value );
    $fields = array();
    foreach ( json_decode( get_option( 'bookly_custom_fields' ) ) as $field ) {
        $fields[ $field->id ] = $field;
    }

    foreach ( $decoded_value as $field ) {
        if ( isset( $fields[ $field->id ] ) ) {
            if ( ( $fields[ $field->id ]->type == 'captcha' ) && ! Captcha\Captcha::validate( $form_id, $field->value ) ) {
                $this->errors['custom_fields'][ $cart_key ][ $field->id ] = __( 'Incorrect code', 'bookly' );
            } elseif ( $fields[ $field->id ]->required && empty ( $field->value ) && $field->value != '0' ) {
                $this->errors['custom_fields'][ $cart_key ][ $field->id ] = __( 'Required', 'bookly' );
            } else {
                /**
                 * Custom field validation for a third party,
                 * if the value is not valid then please add an error message like in the above example.
                 *
                 * @param \stdClass
                 * @param ref array
                 * @param \stdClass
                 */
                do_action_ref_array( 'bookly_validate_custom_field', array( $field, &$this->errors, $fields[ $field->id ] ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code in functions.php:

```
/**
 * Adds the custom validator for postcodes
 */
function postcode_custom_validator_action($field, $errors, $fieldId) {
    if ( $fieldId == 16020 ) {
        $postcodesCoveredSetting = get_theme_mod( 'postcode_textbox' );
        if(!isValidPostcode($field->value, $postcodesCoveredSetting)) {
            // Validator.php says: "if the value is not valid then please add an error message like in the above example."
            // which looks like this:
            // $this->errors['custom_fields'][ $cart_key ][ $field->id ] = __( 'Required', 'bookly' );
            // but $cart_key not passed through it seems?
            $errors['custom_fields'][ $cart_key ][ $field->id ] = __( "Sorry, we only cover " . $postcodesCoveredSetting . " postcode areas at the moment", 'bookly' );
        }
    }
}
add_action ( 'bookly_validate_custom_field', 'postcode_custom_validator_action', 10, 3 ); // 10 is priority, 3 is number of params in array?
```

Comment: You checked the reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action_ref_array, what error you get ?

Comment: `$cart_key` is an undefined variable in your callback. Always enable the [debug mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) when you are writing WP code.

Comment: Very similar to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/272928/help-with-callback-using-do-action-ref-array

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet but somebody suggested this:

```
add_action( 'bookly_validate_custom_field', function ( \stdClass $field, &$errors, $cart_key, \stdClass $field_info ) {
    // Validation by custom_field id
    switch ( $field->id ) {
        case 'id_value':
            if ( /*$invalid == */ true ) {
                $errors['custom_fields'][ $cart_key ][ $field->id ] = __( 'Invalid', 'bookly' );
            }
            break;
    }
}, 10, 4 );
```