# Help with callback using do_action_ref_array

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I've managed to get the behaviour I want by modifying some plugin code. However, I would like to move my modifications outside of the plugin code using the provided hook, but I can't seem make it work. The hook uses do_action_ref_array.

The situation is not helped by the fact that the only way I can find to access the php vars is by sending error messages to the debug.log file.

(like so):

```
function ra_func1($args) {
    $str = print_r($args, true);
    error_log($str);
}
add_action ( 'bookly_validate_custom_field', 'ra_func1', 10, 3);
```

Trouble is there's a mixture of objects and arrays and I'm now really stuck, having spent a lot of time trying to get this working. If anyone could provide a working callback that does what I want I would be very grateful.

Original plugin code:

```
public function validateCustomFields( $value, $form_id, $cart_key )
    {
        $decoded_value = json_decode( $value );
        $fields = array();
        foreach ( json_decode( get_option( 'bookly_custom_fields' ) ) as $field ) {
            $fields[ $field->id ] = $field;
        }

        foreach ( $decoded_value as $field ) {
            if ( isset( $fields[ $field->id ] ) ) {
                if ( ( $fields[ $field->id ]->type == 'captcha' ) && ! Captcha\Captcha::validate( $form_id, $field->value ) ) {
                    $this->errors['custom_fields'][ $cart_key ][ $field->id ] = __( 'Incorrect code', 'bookly' );
                } elseif ( $fields[ $field->id ]->required && empty ( $field->value ) && $field->value != '0' ) {
                    $this->errors['custom_fields'][ $cart_key ][ $field->id ] = __( 'Required', 'bookly' );
                } else {
                    /**
                     * Custom field validation for a third party,
                     * if the value is not valid then please add an error message like in the above example.
                     *
                     * @param \stdClass
                     * @param ref array
                     * @param string
                     * @param \stdClass
                     */
                    do_action_ref_array( 'bookly_validate_custom_field', array( $field, &$this->errors, $cart_key, $fields[ $field->id ] ) );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Code with the beginnings of the functionality I want to add via an external callback:

```
public function validateCustomFields( $value, $form_id, $cart_key )
    {
        $decoded_value = json_decode( $value );
        $fields = array();
        foreach ( json_decode( get_option( 'bookly_custom_fields' ) ) as $field ) {
            $fields[ $field->id ] = $field;
        }

        foreach ( $decoded_value as $field ) {
            if ( isset( $fields[ $field->id ] ) ) {
                if ( ( $fields[ $field->id ]->type == 'captcha' ) && ! Captcha\Captcha::validate( $form_id, $field->value ) ) {
                    $this->errors['custom_fields'][ $cart_key ][ $field->id ] = __( 'Incorrect code', 'bookly' );
                } elseif ( $fields[ $field->id ]->required && empty ( $field->value ) && $field->value != '0' ) {
                    $this->errors['custom_fields'][ $cart_key ][ $field->id ] = __( 'Required', 'bookly' );
                } else {
                    /**
                     * Custom field validation for a third party,
                     * if the value is not valid then please add an error message like in the above example.
                     *
                     * @param \stdClass
                     * @param ref array
                     * @param string
                     * @param \stdClass
                     */

                    //

                    if ($fields[$field->id]->id == 12372){
                     $this->errors['custom_fields'][ $cart_key ][ $field->id ] = __( 'Post Code Error', 'bookly' );                      
                                         }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature exists because I bugged them to implement it :)

- https://support.booking-wp-plugin.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207263389-Add-a-WordPress-hook-for-custom-validators-on-the-custom-fields?page=1#community_comment_115001021885

Using it confused me as  well but somebody finally replied to this just the other day with this snippet:

```
add_action( 'bookly_validate_custom_field', function ( \stdClass $field, &$errors, $cart_key, \stdClass $field_info ) {
    // Validation by custom_field id
    switch ( $field->id ) {
        case 'id_value':
            if ( /*$invalid == */ true ) {
                $errors['custom_fields'][ $cart_key ][ $field->id ] = __( 'Invalid', 'bookly' );
            }
            break;
    }
}, 10, 4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom function in functions.php with name of `bookly_validate_custom_field` and pass 5 arguments to that function

For example

```
function bookly_validate_custom_field ( $field, &$errors, $cart_key, $field_id ) {
if ($field_id] == 12372){
$errors['custom_fields'][ $cart_key ][ $field_id ] = __( 'Post Code Error', 'bookly' );
}}
```

**Don't forget to put '&' symbol in front of errors variable.**

Reference link:
[do_action_ref_array](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action_ref_array)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Also, it goes against my understanding of how hooks function in WP. I thought the function name could be anything, but is hooked in by use of something like `add_action ( 'bookly_validate_custom_field', 'ra_func1', 10, 4);` No?. Any further ideas?

Comment: Did to add add_action statement in your code.. add_action( 'bookly_validate_custom_field','bookly_validate_custom_field',10,5)b